# Cakephp throws undefined method but the method exists

Tags: cakephp

i created custom classes in the plugin. This class contains several methods. Unfortunately sometimes crashes on Exception

```
 Error: Fatal Error (1): Call to undefined method DateTools::getUserDateFromSQL() in ...
```

but this method is in the class :(. Unfortunately an error occurs infrequently  and can not even repeat it.

```
 My class in plugin Tools (folder Lib) 
  class DateTools {

    public function getUserDateFromSQL($value) {
        if(empty($value)) return $value;
        return Date("d.m.Y H:i", $this->getDateFromSQLDate($value));
    }
 ...
 ...
 ...
```

The place where source crash.

```
 App::import('DateTools', 'Tools.Lib');

  class SomeController extends SomeParentAppController {

    public function someMethod($arraysDate) {
      $dateTools = new DateTools();
      $result[$key] = $dateTools->getUserDateFromSQL($value);
...
...
...
```

Thanks for help

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Whenever receiving errors, please always post **the _complete_ error**, that is, **including the _full_ stacktrace** (ideally copied from the logs where it is available in a properly readable fashion), even if the problem might be obvious to people who are familiar with CakePHP!

Answer (score 2):

The syntax used to include the class is incorrect

You could use `App::uses` instead of `App::import`

```
App::uses('DateTools', 'Tools.Lib');
```

### [Syntax for App::import()](https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/app.html#including-files-with-app-import)

### [Syntax for App::uses()](https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/app.html#App::uses)